# Indent paragraph aligned to title

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

at the beginning of my thesis I want to give a short definition of the most important terms. Usually this is done with 1-3 lines of text. I want the word to be printed in bold and then give the explanation right afterwards. If the text is more than one line, I want the following lines to be indented but aligned to the first word that is not printed bold (in this case "Der", the indent varies with the length of the word I want to explain):

**Entzugsleistung**: Der Wärmequelle entzogene Leistung, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe. Beispielsweise W/m, W/m\textsuperscript{2}, kW/(m\textsuperscript{3}/h)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}

\paragraph*{Entzugsleistung:} Der Wärmequelle entzogene Leistung, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe. Beispielsweise W/m, W/m\textsuperscript{2}, kW/(m\textsuperscript{3}/h)

\paragraph*{Entzugsarbeit:} Der Wärmequelle über einen gewissen Zeitraum entzogene Wärmemenge, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe und Zeit. Beispielsweise W/(m$\cdot$a), W/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$a)

\paragraph*{Entzugsleistung:} \hangindent=3cm Der Wärmequelle entzogene Leistung, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe. Beispielsweise W/m, W/m\textsuperscript{2}, kW/(m\textsuperscript{3}/h)

\end{document}
```

Bascially, the same is done with the captions of a figure but in plain text I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Kind regards,
Pjayy

Answer (score 1):

The magic command is called `\@hangfrom`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\shortdefinition[1]{%
  \@hangfrom{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{paragraph}#1: }\ignorespaces}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\shortdefinition{Entzugsleistung} Der Wärmequelle entzogene Leistung, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe. Beispielsweise W/m, W/m\textsuperscript{2}, kW/(m\textsuperscript{3}/h)

\shortdefinition{Entzugsarbeit} Der Wärmequelle über einen gewissen Zeitraum entzogene Wärmemenge, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe und Zeit. Beispielsweise W/(m$\cdot$a), W/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$a)

\shortdefinition{Entzugsleistung} \hangindent=3cm Der Wärmequelle entzogene Leistung, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Größe. Beispielsweise W/m, W/m\textsuperscript{2}, kW/(m\textsuperscript{3}/h)

\end{document}
```

Also you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package. With it your units could be written like this and would get consistent formatting:

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\year}{a}
\si{\watt\per\metre}
\si{\watt\per\square\metre}
\si{\kilo\watt\hour\per\cubic\metre}
\si{\watt\per\metre\per\year}
\si{\watt\per\square\metre\per\year}
```

Results (with the usage of `siunitx`):
[image]

With the usage of `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}` in the preamble:
[image]

Comment: thank you so much! It works perfectly :)
About the siunitx: My tutor and me talked about it but he prefers it to be written like this...

Comment: @Pjayyy do you mean without the usage of `siunitx` or with `/` as the `\per` symbol? If the latter: Use `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}` to use a slash for each per instead of a negative exponent.